# Error creating a module with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to develop a R module using Rcpp. For it I followed a ([Dirk Eddelbuettel's guide](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/rcpp_workshop_advanced_user2012.pdf))

The files of my library have the content:

functions.hpp:

```
class myclass {
    // my atributes and functions
}
```

functions.cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class myclass;

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(myclass)

#include "functions.hpp"

//Implementation of my funcions

RCPP_MODULE(mymodule){
    class_<myclass>("myclass")
    .constructor()
    .method("oneMethod", &myclass::oneMethod)
    //more methods
;
```

}

mypackageExports.R:

```
.onLoad<-function(libname, pkgname){
    require("methods")
    loadRcppModules()
}
```

DESCRIPTION:

```
...
LazyLoad: yes
Depends: methods, Rcpp (>= 0.12.4)
LinkingTo: Rcpp
RcppModules: mymodule
```

NAMESPACE:

```
useDynLib(mypackage)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
import(Rcpp)
```

When I compile the library with the command `R CMD INSTALL mypackage` I have the error:

```
installing to /home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/mypackage/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

*** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call(Module__classes_info, xp)
 2: Module(m, pkg, mustStart = TRUE)
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch({    mod <- Module(m, pkg, mustStart = TRUE)    if (isTRUE(direct)) {        populate(mod, ns)    }    else {        forceAssignInNamespace(m, mod, ns)    }    assign(.moduleMetaName(m), mod, envir = ns)}, error = function(e) {    stop(sprintf("failed to load module %s from package %s\n%s",         m, pkg, conditionMessage(e)))})
 7: loadRcppModules()
 8: fun(libname, pkgname)
 9: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
10: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
11: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
12: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
13: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
14: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
15: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
16: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
17: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
18: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
19: try({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
20: library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)
21: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
22: suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib,     character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE))
23: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
24: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
25: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
26: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
27: try(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib,     character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)))
28: tools:::.test_load_package("mypackage", "/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
```

Can anyone (@DirkEddelbuettel, my Rcpp's guru) tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to send this question to the mailing list if you want Dirk's attention, afaik he is most apt to respond to direct questions at the intended venue for doing so.

Comment: Sorry because I have not used a mailing list but, the answer would be public? I will do it if anyone can not help me, but asking here the answer is public and it could be useful for others

Comment: All the postings are available, they are only mailed to subscribers. Anyone can read your posts, and the answers are public.

Comment: This question does not meet the minimally reproducible example requirement as it omits the core class `myclass` that the question is based upon. Therefore, I'm voting to close, which is a pity since this would make a great question for folks interested in modules...

Comment: Ok, I will provided a simple code, but the problem is not related with the omitted code

Comment: I second the recommendation for rcpp-devel.  I believe I have recommended it to (anonymous, booooh) user 'bra_racing' before.  Oh well.  Your loss.

Comment: What can I say? You rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I have discovered the problem was related with a conflict with a dependence I am consuming and the include of the Rcpp.h file

Answer (score 2):

Well, you used a guide from 2012. Sometimes things change.  I would recommend to *also* looks at *current* packages using Modules.

Here you no longer need

```
.onLoad<-function(libname, pkgname){
    require("methods")
    loadRcppModules()
}
```

Since about 2013, all we ask for is a single `loadModule("moduleName", TRUE)` in an R, really any R file.

For example, the *entire* content of the `R/` directory of the [RcppCNPy package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppCNPy) is this

```
edd@max:~/git/rcppcnpy(master)$ cat R/*.R 

loadModule("cnpy", TRUE)


edd@max:~/git/rcppcnpy(master)$
```

as the package defines a single module `cnpy`.

Similarly, we no longer need the `RcppModules: ...` line in DESCRIPTION.

Lastly, the Rcpp package itself contains a fully working package with Modules for its own unit tests.  You can look at that too.

**Edit:** You probably also want on `importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)` or alike in `NAMESPACE` which will instantiate Rcpp.

Comment: The error continues, but you are totally right, I did not notice the date of the guide. Sorry for any incovenience

Comment: Yes, just start from a small _working_ example such as the one in `inst/unitTests/testRcppModule` or one from CRAN and take it from there. And I just added another point re `NAMESPACE`.